# Is there a category (or rather a mathematical theory) for which we know a lot about, but not whether its object class is empty or not?

Tags: category-theory, philosophy, meta-math

this is a bit of a vague question so let me describe a bit what motivates it: Yesterday I was reading the Wikipedia article about perfect numbers, where I find the section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers quite interesting. It appears that we know a good amount of properties that odd perfect numbers must satisfy, but what we don't know is if there actualy *are* odd perfect numbers.

What I then asked myself is if this phenomenon occurs on the level of category theory, i.e. is there a (say concrete) category, which is quite well understood (where, I don't know, limits, products and some structure theorems might exist), but where we don't know a single example of its objects.

I mean, usually all introductory courses in any mathematical topic start in rather the same pattern: first we define the category of objects we're interested in, say topological spaces or groups or manifolds, then we give concrete examples (say R with the topology induced by the euclidian metric for a topological space, symmetric groups for groups or the n-sphere for manifolds) and then we show some stability properties such as "the cartesian product of two topological spaces with the product topology is again a topological space" et cetera.

But do you know about a topic, where step 1 and 3 can be done, but not step 2 because we don't know any concrete example?

Sorry for the vagueness of the question, but I hope you'll understand what I mean.

Thank you!

Best, jgrk

Comment: This kind of phenomenon appears all over mathematics. Whenever one tries to prove the non-existence of something, one tries to understand what it can look like, and thus one ends up understanding a lot of things that cannot happen for the object, without necessarily succeeding in proving that it does not exist. That said, I don't know of any categorical example, but I would guess there are some, though maybe not as striking as your example.

Comment: Mind you, you could always define a category of finite sets having an odd perfect number as their cardinal ;) However, this hardly qualifies as a categorical example !

Comment: Yeah, I bet the then so called Jgrk-Darné-Category will be a very active field of research in the next decades :D unfortunately this category is not even closed under unions since such a union might have even cardinality ;-)

Comment: I highly doubt that any experienced mathematician does step 1 before step 2. Maybe it is written up in this order by some authors, but the process to find these categories is different.

Comment: Also, for me, a category being well-understood implies that we know (lots of) objects of it. It is not just the existence of (co)limits or categorical structures on it.

Comment: But of course you can artificially cook up examples. For example, let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of complex manifolds *not* satisfying the Hodge conjecture ...

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers, Martin. Yes, of course, those artificial kind of examples do count in a way. But do you know in which way it is possible to assert stability properties for those kind of examples? For instance, if we have given two complex manifolds not satisfying the hodge conjecture, is it true, that their cartesian product doesn't satisfy hodge as well?

Comment: If you're willing to question the axiom of choice (I'm not), then how about a category whose objects are infinite products of nonempty sets?

Answer (score 2):

It is a soft question, so here is my personal opinion:

No. When you think to know a lot about a category, but don't know if it has any objects, you don't know a lot (in fact, very little) about that category.